# Hide JSON fields

Tags: java, hibernate, jackson

I have the hibernate entity, that pass to controller as parameter and I want to hide userID field. I use it for database operations and don`t need to show it as input parameter

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "user_sessions")
    public class UserSession{

    @Column(name="uid")
    private Long userID;
    @Id
    @Column(name="access_key")
    private String accessKey;
    @Column(name="secret_key")
    private String secretKey;

    public Long getUserID() {
    return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(Long s) {
        this.userID = s;
    }`
```

Comment: You can try to annotate `userID` with [`@JsonIgnore`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations) or `@JsonIgnoreProperties`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "user_sessions")
    public class UserSession{

    @Column(name="uid")
    private Long userID;
    @Id
    @Column(name="access_key")
    private String accessKey;
    @Column(name="secret_key")
    private String secretKey;
    @JsonIgnore
    public Long getUserID() {
    return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(Long s) {
        this.userID = s;
    }`
```

Now if you use jackson like

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();   
String json =  mapper.writeValueAsString(userSession);
```

then it will simple ignore the `userId`

or you can do as below

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "user_sessions")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties( { "userID" })
    public class UserSession{

    @Column(name="uid")
    private Long userID;
    @Id
    @Column(name="access_key")
    private String accessKey;
    @Column(name="secret_key")
    private String secretKey;

    public Long getUserID() {
    return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(Long s) {
        this.userID = s;
    }`
```